# adding ImageViews to Relative Layout using Drag and Drop

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I am pretty new to Android and I am making an app with a Vertical Linear Layout at the bottom of the screen with a list of imageViews going across the screen. Each of these are draggable onto the main part of the screen, however, if I drag one of the imageviews on the far right of the layout, it will drop the view far to the left of the actual drop point. What is strange is that if I try dragging the first imageview in the linearlayout (the one on the left side) it will land right under where I drop it.

My onDrag and onTouch Listeners...

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

     @Override
      public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        float X = event.getX();
        float Y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

          break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        

          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:


          View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
          ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
          owner.removeView(view);
          container = (RelativeLayout) v;
          container.setLayoutParams(findViewById(R.id.drawingbackground).getLayoutParams());

          container.addView(view);

          view.setX(X-(view.getWidth()/2));
          view.setY(Y-(view.getHeight()/2));
          view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

          default:
          break;
        }
        return true;
      }
}
```

and the OnTouch...

```
final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
      public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

          ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
          DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
          view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);

          return true;

        }  if(motionEvent.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            view.performClick();
        }



        return false;

      }


}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml.Use Relative Layout Instead of LinearLayout and Fix their height and width.It would work pretty fine.